# Placing rooks peacefully on a chessboard

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification, contest-math

How many ways are there to place n rooks on an $n\times n$ chessboard such that none of them are attacking each other and the placement remains invariant when the board is halfrotated

Solution:

A half rotation reflects each piece across the origin. Hence, if we can place $n/2$ pieces, the placement of the rest of the pieces would be decided by reflecting each across the origin. The first piece has $n^2$ possible placements. No matter where this is placed, it rules out $2n-1$ choices leaving $(n - 1)^2$ choices for the second and so on. Proceeding in this manner, we get a total of $\frac{n!^2}{(n/2)!^2}$ possibilities. However, this is wrong as the given answer is $2^{n/2}$ $×$ $(n/2)!$.I don't know where I've gone wrong. This problem was taken from the book 'Problem solving strategies' by Arthur engel

Comment: I agree, $2^n\cdot n!$ cannot be correct.

Comment: When you place the first piece, you must also place the corresponding half-rotated piece, so aren't you removing $4n-4$ possibilities for the next piece (unless the first piece is placed in the centre for $n$ odd)?

Comment: @Peter the 'given' answer that I wrote wasn't the actual given answer. I've updated it

Comment: But you're not allowed to place the second piece in all $(n-1)^2$ positions that are left over without potentially breaking rotation-invariance later when you do the rotation to fill in the last $n/2$ pieces.

Comment: @Dan Rust yeah youre right. I'm gonna try again using that and see if I get the correct answer

Comment: @Dan Rust. Using that, and also the fact that I forgot to divide by (n/2)!, since the rooks are indistinguishable, we get the total number to be n(n-2)(n-4)...(2)×$2^{n/2}$ = $2^n$ × $(n/2)!$, which still dosent quite match

Comment: You need to divide by $2^{n/2}$ because not only could you have laid the first $n/2$ down in a different order to arrive at the same board, but you could have also laid the $i$th piece at its half-rotated position and arrived at the same board, so every piece you lay from the first $n/2$ pieces gives rise to $2$ choices. That is, you're overcounting at a rate of $2^{n/2}(n/2)!$.

Comment: @Dan Rust. Alright I've understood, thank you so much